# Line up rspec lets when formatting code in Rubymine

Tags: ruby, rspec, ide, rubymine

Rubymine generally formats code very well, one thing I cannot seem to get it to do though is to line up my `lets` in my RSpec specs.

Given unformatted code like this:

```rb
let(:foo) { :bar }
let(:another_foo) { :foo_two }
```

I would like the reformat code feature in Rubymine to line up the `let` values:

```rb
let(:foo)         { :bar }
let(:another_foo) { :foo_two }
```

Any suggestions (even outside of Rubymine) on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [AlignTab](https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab) sublime bundle and try using it. It basically gives you the ability to align by special symbol in your case you can mark the `let` definitions you are interested in and align by `{`. I am not using RubyMine but I think it has a Textmate bundles support. Try using [Tabular for Textmate](https://github.com/textmate/tabular.tmbundle) if this does not work.

Comment: AlignTab is very powerful, check it's examples https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab/wiki/Examples

Comment: String Manipulation is very nice: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162 you can install it through the plugins dialogue too